# ¿Cómo implementar la capa de lógica de negocio usando Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

He creado el modelo de la base de datos usando Entity Framework, el contexto generado se llama **Entidades**. EF creó una clase llamada **personas**, la cual representa la tabla con el mismo nombre. Estoy usando EF como la capa de acceso a datos **DAL**, y para la capa de **lógica de negocios** he creado una clase llamada **PersonasBLL**, dentro de la cual hago uso de una instancia del contexto para realizar las operaciones necesarias. Por ejemplo:

```
//método de la clase PersonasBLL
public List<personas> GetPersonas(){
   Entidades e = new Entidades();
   List<personas> personas = e.personas.ToList();
   e.Dispose();
   return personas;
}
```

Quiero saber si el enfoque que usé para separar el **acceso a datos** y la **lógica de negocios** es correcto y tiene sentido, o como se puede mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas en el camino correcto. El acceso a datos tiene que ser transparente  para la aplicacion. No puede haber relacion entre la aplicacion y la fuente de datos.

La forma mas usada para hacer este tipo de separacion es utilizando interfaces.  Las interfaces no están atadas a una implementacion, sino al contrario: atan a la implementacion al contrato de la interfaz. Eso las hace flexibles porque le aseguran a la aplicacion que sin importar la implementacion que tenga, su *apariciencia*(interfaz) siempre sera la misma.

Por ejemplo si se usa sql server y ese requerimiento cambie a leer archivos de texto cuando la base de datos este fuera de servicio, con interfaces seria simple. Solo habría que crear 2 implementaciones: 1 para EF y otra para los archivos de texto.

Hagamos un ejemplo. Vamos a definir nuestro contrato como una interfaz y la llamaeremos `IPersonasBLL`:

```
public interface IPersonasBLL 
{
   List<personas> GetPersonas();
   personas GetPersonaPorId(int id);
}
```

Ahora hagamos la implementacion con entity framework para cuando el servicio sql este activo:

```
public class PersonasBLL_EntityFramework : IPersonasBLL
{
  public List<persona> GetPersonas()
  {
   Entidades e = new Entidades();
   List<personas> personas = e.personas.ToList();
   e.Dispose();
   return personas;
  }

  public personas GetPersonasPorId(int id)
  {
     Entidades e = new Entidades();
     personas personas = e.personas.Find(id);
     e.Dispose();

    return personas;
   }
}
```

Ahora la implemetacion para cuando el servicio de sql este offline:

```
public class  FueraServicioIPersonasBLL : IPersonasBLL
{
    public class PersonasBLL_EntityFramework : IPersonasBLL
    {
      public List<persona> GetPersonas()
      {
         var datos = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("ruta_archivo.txt");

         // convertimos el texto del archivo al objeto List<personas>
         // ...
         // ...

        return personas;
      }

      public personas GetPersonasPorId(int id)
      {
         var datos = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("ruta_archivo.txt");

         // convertimos el texto del archivo al objeto personas
         // ...
         // ...

        return persona;
       }
    }
}
```

Entonces solo tendrias que saber si el servicio esta activo o no para saber cual implementacion utilizar:

```
IPersonasBLL servicioPersonas;

if(servicioSqlActivo())
{
  servicioPersonas = new PersonasBLL_EntityFramework();
}
else{
  servicioPersonas = new FueraServicioIPersonasBLL();
}

personas = servicioPersonas.GetPersonas();
```

La aplicación puede utilizar el metodo `GetPersonas()` donde sea ya que la interfaz se lo asegura y no importaria si es de un `.txt` o de sql server que esta extrayendo la data. Simplemente es transparente para aplicacion.